# Django get attribute of field value (of foreign key)

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I need to get an attribute (code) from a foreign key (Option) for each field in a model object (Jacket).

Obviously what I have is wrong. It only returns the field value's Id. I need field value's attribute 'code'.

Template:

```
{% for field, value in jacket.get_fields %}

<tr>
  <td>
    {{field}}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{value}}
  </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
def get_fields(self):
    return [(field.name, field.value_to_string(self)) for field in Jacket._meta.fields]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right way, but you need to use the [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) on your instance.

See this example:

```
>>> my_instance = MyModel.objects.first()
>>> field_names = [field.name for field in MyModel._meta.fields]
>>> print(field_names)
['id', 'title', 'created_by', 'created_on']
>>> for field_name in field_names:
...     print('{field}: {value}'.format(field=field_name, value=getattr(my_instance, field_name)))
...
id: 1
title: My instance
created_by: user
created_on: 2018-06-08 06:58:26.927950
```

By using the `getattr`, you can retrieve the Value from a attribute name, its just a Python function, that work in any object.

In your case, you should use the `getattr` on the `self`, as you are using a Jacket instance on your template. You may have issues with relations, lets suppose that you have a `ManyToManyField` inside your `Jacket` model, the `getattr` will return a `RelatedManager` object. But you can handle that on your `get_fields` method.